# Content is set more than once

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Whilst playing about with WPF in Visual Studio 2013, I have been presented with an error:

> Error 2   The property 'Content' is set more than once.
>
> Error 1   The property "Content" can only be set once

Now, first of all. I turn to google for the error message & got presented with a top results linking to StackOverflow.

[XAML - The property 'Content' is set more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868713/xaml-the-property-content-is-set-more-than-once)

[the property 'Content' is set more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331456/the-property-content-is-set-more-than-once)

[Property content is set more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384395/property-content-is-set-more-than-once)

Including a MSDN post:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/686be076-954f-4373-a2e6-fc42a6a27718/error-the-property-content-is-set-more-than-once?forum=wpf

Whilst being presented with an *informative* collection of tailored solutions based on the original posters code, I have yet to come across an actual basic solution detailing the reasons of this error (XAML Novice) Whilst this may be a duplicate of multiple reported problems. I personally would rather avoid posting a problematic code to get a tailored solution. I'd much rather come here and ask the community reasons as to why a novice XAMP/WPF Developer might encounter this application and solutions & not so much top, top best practices. Rather words of advice from the more WPF/XAMP Developers on how to easily identify the solution and continue on with furter debugging steps in the future

---

For argument sake:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFT.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="197.198" Width="427.95">
    <TextBlock>Hello</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock>World</TextBlock>
</Window>
```

Comment: You need to post your code to get answers.

Comment: Sounds like you are setting it in multiple places.  Maybe databinding in xaml and also trying to set it in code. But without code... Who knows?

Comment: Did you bother reading the links you post to? The very first sentence of the MSDN post's accepted answer tells you _exactly_ the "reasons of _[sic]_ this error": _...(Control X)...is a ContentControl meaning that it can only have one child element inside of it_

Comment: For arguments sake, I'll provide the XAML for a reference, but i'm not looking for a tailored solution

Comment: 3/4 of the answers you link to are explicit about the underlying problem. You are setting the `.Content` property to multiple `object`s, when the `.Content` property can only be set to a single `object`.

Comment: You need to specify a panel to contain the TextBlocks... Wrap them in <Grid> or <StackPanel> or any of the other panels. You need to have a single root element for a Window.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A window can only contains 1 element.

In your code

```
<Window x:Class="WPFT.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="197.198" Width="427.95">
    <TextBlock>Hello</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock>World</TextBlock>
</Window>
```

your window have 2 textblock
u shoudl try something like

```
<Window x:Class="WPFT.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="197.198" Width="427.95">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock>Hello</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>World</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Whilst this does solve the isolated problem on my end. It's not an in-depth analysis as to why one might encounter this error

Comment: What part of "a window can only contains 1 element" is not clear.

Comment: The Window control have a Content property and MSDN mention that an content is Text or an Object http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content(v=vs.110).aspx . So you put a container like Grid, StackPanel, ... These control don't have a content, they have childrens. After that each container have their way to present other object like Column, Row or side-by-side.

Comment: Doing diference between Control with content and COntrol with container, let you do stuff like the button in [tag:Jaime Still] example (Button have content, so by puting a container control u can put more than one element in).

Answer (score 6):

If you are setting more than one element inside of any UIElement with the Content dependency property, you will get this error. You need to wrap multiple elements inside of a panel so that the Content property only has one child element. For instance...

```
<Button>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image />
        <TextBlock />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>

<Border>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock />
        <Image />
        <DatePicker />
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

The areas between the Button and Border elements are shorthand for specifying:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Content>
        <!-- Content goes here -->
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Comment: Great to know. Tried wrapping a `Grid` in a `Canvas`, for arguments sake:
`<Canvas><Button><Grid>` in a similar example to the one you have shown so to obtain _two_ Grids. Yay!